# same content is getting while reading a file in java

Tags: java, file, filereader

I have created a FileReader object.

```
public String getFileContent(){

   StringBuilder filecontent= new StringBuilder();

   FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader("D:/myfile");

   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


   while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

      filecontent.append(bufferedReader.readLine());

   }    

   return filecontent.toString;
}
```

The problem I face is that the function always returns the same string even if the file content is changed.

Anyone to help???

Comment: You read _two lines_ from the file. Also, if you use Java 7+, please use java.nio.file instead.

Answer (score 0):

append the variable `line` since you store it to that variable. The problem is you're calling the `readline()` twice

like this:

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { 
      filecontent.append(line); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You received an answer already, but it seems that what you're doing could be achieved way better in Java 8:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("D:/myfile");
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
Charset fileEncoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String fileContents = new String(fileBytes, fileEncoding);
```

If you're not on Java 8, you can use Apache Commons IO's [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to get the `String`:

```
File file = new File("D:/myfile");
String fileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

My advice here is leverage the JDK and existing libraries as much as possible. It leads to cleaner code that is easier to maintain.